# Problem Installing GIMP?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install latest GIMP on Loki 0.4.1.

But every time I try to download the packages I get error like the following :

```
E: Unable to locate package pythonany
```

Note : I am trying to install by using the following commands :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

sudo apt-get update
```

and then :

getdebs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

package=gimp

apt-cache depends "$package" | grep Depends: >> deb.list

sed -i -e 's/[<>|:]//g' deb.list

sed -i -e 's/Depends//g' deb.list

sed -i -e 's/ //g' deb.list

filename="deb.list"

while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    apt-get download "$name"
done < "$filename"

apt-get download "$package"
```

for downloading them for offline install.

---

**Maccer**
: Thanks for replying. I was quite anxious.
I am totally new to Linux. Elementary OS is my first Linux distro.

Anyway, I can install GIMP 2.8.16 without that ppa.
But I should be able to install GIMP 2.8.22 using that ppa.
So I want to install GIMP 2.8.22 or later in any possible ways. [ Except compile from source ]
The problem is the following :

- I should be able to install GIMP 2.10.0 using that ppa.
- But even with the ppa I can only get access to GIMP 2.8.22.
- 2.8.22 is no problem.
- I just want to use latest 2.8.x if I will get access only to older
  versions.

I tried to install 2.8.22 and got that error :

```
E: Unable to locate package pythonany
```

Where can I get "pythonany" ?

Is 16.04.3 supported anymore ?

Why does the repository offer 2.8.16 instead of 2.8.22?

Anyway, I just want to use at least 2.8.22 or 2.10.0.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Gimp is available from the ubuntu repos already, so you don't need any ppa.

If you execute `apt download gimp` it will download a deb file of gimp to the folder where you have terminal open (usually /home).

I recommend also to delete that ppa if you don't need it. Adding ppas is a security risk to your system. You can do so with `sudo add-apt-repository --delete ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`

---

If you need a newer version of gimp, for example 2.10, you can download it from [here](https://download.gimp.org/mirror/pub/gimp/v2.10/). That's the official site of the gimp organization. You need to download `gimp-2.10.0.tar.bz2` .

Since it's a compressed package and you probably don't want to install it from source I'm going to explain an alternative way of doing it. With this you are going to convert that file to a .deb file and then you can install it using apt while still receiving updates if a more recent version of gimp is available on the ubuntu repos.

First you need to install alien with `sudo apt install alien`. Now you go to the folder where you've downloaded that `gimp*.tar.bz2` package and you press right click > open on terminal. Execute `sudo alien -d gimp*`, that's going to create a .deb file, may take some minutes to complete.

Now that you have a .deb file you can install it with `sudo apt install -f ./gimp*.deb`. When it's finished installing you can delete the .deb package with `sudo rm gimp*.deb`

With this you should have the lastest stable gimp version. This procedure can also be applied to any other app that comes in a .tar.bz or similar package.

Comment: He mentioned the "latest" gimp, so likely 3.0, which isn't available in the repos yet. You can only get it via PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest checking out flatpak and snap(snacraft.io) app delivery platforms, they offer crossplatform packages, it's so convenient.

gimp is in the flatpak one, this is the [installation guide](https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS/) for elementaryOS with their PPA

this is the [link](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP) to the app in the store. one of the ways to install gimp via flatpak is from the command line

```
sudo flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
```

Check them out, they have a lot of great apps, and they are self-updating too.